# Flag columns based on values in it in R

Tags: r, filter, flags

I am trying to identify data frame columns where the columns have a single character value `tree`.

Here is an example dataset.

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5),
             var.1 = c(5,6,7,"tree",4),
             var.2 = c("tree","tree","tree","tree","tree"),
             var.3 = c(4,5,8,9,1),
             var.4 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
             var.5 = c("tree","tree",NA,"tree","tree"))

> df
  id var.1 var.2 var.3 var.4 var.5
1  1     5  tree     4    NA  tree
2  2     6  tree     5    NA  tree
3  3     7  tree     8    NA  <NA>
4  4  tree  tree     9    NA  tree
5  5     4  tree     1    NA  tree
```

I would flag the `var.2` `var.4` and `var.5` variables since they have all `tree` or all `NA` or both `NA` and `tree` values in it. When there is a numeric value in the column, I do not want to flag that column.

> flagged
> [1] "var.2" "var.4" "var.5"

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option with `tidyverse` - `select` the columns that have only `NA` values (`all(is.na`) or (`|`) having only `'tree'` as value (`all(.x == "tree"`)

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   select(where(~ all(is.na(.x))| all(.x == "tree", na.rm = TRUE))) %>% 
   names
[1] "var.2" "var.4" "var.5"
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
 names(df)[!colSums(df != "tree", na.rm = TRUE)]
[1] "var.2" "var.4" "var.5"
```

Comment: with the `Base R` solution. Using the double negative where 1st is to find `not 'tree'` and 2nd to find it's opposite.  Very cool

Answer (score 2):

Use of `|` which is virtually arbitrarily expandable and which `colSums` equal `nrow`.

```
names(which(colSums(df == 'tree' | is.na(df)) == nrow(df)))
# [1] "var.2" "var.4" "var.5"
```